# ui select 2 selected value doesnt change - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select2

i m using ui.select2 for dropdowns

**Scenario**
i have an ajax call that return drop down values

```
document.dropDownDocStatuses = [
            { key: 0, value: 'All active (' + response.totalDocuments + ')' },
            { key: 1, value: 'Draft (' + response.draft + ')' }            
        ];
```

in html i have

```
<select ui-select2 class="form-control font-12px input-style3 " 
ng-model="document.dropDownDocStatus"        
ng-change="document.filterDocuments()">
<option ng-repeat="documents in document.dropDownDocStatuses"  value="{{documents.key}}">({{documents.value}})</option>  </select>
```

user have selected value 
[image]

**Issue**
now when i update any value of dropdown using

```
  _document.dropDownDocStatuses[_document.dropDownDocStatus].value++;
                _document.dropDownDocStatuses[1].value++;
```

valuge gets updated but it doesnt change selected value text whereas if i click on dropdown i get changed value in dropdown 
[image]

can someone guide me how can i fix the issue, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

i have just come across the same issues as yours, and the root cause is the ng-model field, which you should not use the "options" field to store the ng-model, try to create another field for ng-model, and you will be able to select the value.

e.g.

```
document.dropDownDocStatuses = [
            { key: 0, value: 'All active (' + response.totalDocuments + ')' },
            { key: 1, value: 'Draft (' + response.draft + ')' }            
        ];
document.selectedDocStatus = [];
```

and in HTML:

```
<select ui-select2 class="form-control font-12px input-style3 " 
ng-model="document.selectedDocStatus"        
ng-change="document.filterDocuments()">
<option ng-repeat="documents in document.dropDownDocStatuses"  value="{{documents.key}}">({{documents.value}})</option>  </select>
```

then you should be able to select the value successfully.